# how to fix, blank page when trying to use history push in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, history.js

I am working on a APP, where I created a button that navigates you to other page. I imported react native router and use history from react-router dom.

I created seperated folder with login routs (when user is on login screen he can move to sign-up)

Loginrouts.js :

[image]

than I created login.js where the button is, it uses useHistory.push() and it calls signup from loginroute.js

[image]

But when button is pressed it only shows blank screen, anyone knows why?